# Как правильно использовать в Google Analytic 4 добавление и удаление продуктов из корзины?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Подскажите, есть вопросы по функциям добавления/удаления из корзины
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?client_type=gtag#remove_from_cart

Если продукта в корзине не было и я добавил 3 продукта - я треккаю add_to_cart и передаю quantity 3,

А если я потом ещё добавляю 2, то как правильно писать ? quantity передавать 5 или 2 ?

Точно такой же вопрос с удалением, так как я не понял - зачем в удалении quantity, если он теоретически всегда 0 должен быть, но видимо я не понял.

Тоесть если было 5, а я убираю 1 продукт - я должен здесь писать remove_from_cart с quantity = 1. ? или перетирать и писать add_to_cart с quantity 4.  ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]